# Find value of selected item in Drop down menu

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu in an ASPX page along the lines of:

```
 <form>
 <select name="cars">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="fiat" selected="selected">Fiat</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
 </form>
```

That is dynamically generated from another controller (value and label).

After the user selects one of the options I need to find out what the selected value/label (will be the same) is so I can hit an update button and retrieve the data on that option.

What would be the easiest way to find out the value of the user "selected" option?

Comment: @Ozaki , Why you do not use from Asp:dropdownlist ?

Comment: That may be the way to get it working was kinda hoping I wouldn't have to is all.

Comment: Even as <asp:dropdownlist /> it still renders as a <select>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Either use an `<asp:dropdownlist />` control.</s>

Just realised this MVC.

The simplest way would be to use the `Request.Form` collection, eg:

```
Request.Form["cars"]
```

Or you can specify them as properties on your controller:

```
public ActionResult ControllerMethod(string cars){...}
```

Or you can use [model binders](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/08/29/how-to-use-the-asp-net-mvc-modelbinder.aspx)

Comment: Yeah was just working on pretty much what you posted but was a tad confused with it still. 
Thanks :)